# How to update or create a new record in a table when a view is used to display existing records in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a page where events data alongside the organizing club is displayed. Since events and clubs are stored in different table, I created a view what combines records from the two table. The report part of the page is working just fine. But when it comes to creating a new event and updating the event i am facing an error.
[image]

When i created the pages I selected event_id and other unnecessary club columns to not be inclued in the report and also in the form

[image]

I think the error is occurring because I am using the views for the data rather than actual tables. How may i tackle this issue.

Also when i used actual tables to get the data since I didn't include the 'event_id' column in the form(because i don't want a unchangeable primary key to appear in the report or in the form), it was giving me some error stating I cannot insert null value in 'event_id' column. How may I solve this problem too?

SQL script for view table is given below.

```
create or replace view "V_EVENT" as
SELECT event.*, club_name
FROM event
LEFT JOIN (club_event INNER JOIN club ON club_event.club_id = club.club_id)
ON event.event_id = club_event.event_id
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use views as a proxy for table updates, but they need to remain key-preserved, as the error suggests.

This means you should at least be selecting the primary key in the view, and don't join anywhere that loses that PK uniqueness.

Sometimes it make complain because ambiguity exists, such as a missing foreign key constraint. Further examples explored [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=key-preserved-table-concept-in-join-view-201603)

You can still include these vital columns in APEX so that you can define them in the meta-data accordingly as the primary key, you can just set them to 'hidden'.

But you've still got to set the value for new records somwhere, such as a computation, trigger, or use an [identity column](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/10/synchronise-sequence-value-with-12c-identity-column.html).

Comment: I went to the links you provided and read a bit. I am still confuse on how can i preserve key in my view table and update or create events. I have edited my original question to include the statement that the view table uses for data. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What is returned when you query all_updatable_columns for V_EVENT? What relationship/constraints exist between event and club_event?

Comment: event and club_event has one to many relation. Same is for club and club_events

Comment: in my database a event can be organized by one or more clubs. So there is a one to may relation between event and club_event table. That meas if a event has multiple club organizers, same row which same value for the primary key will appear multiple times in the view table. Is this the reason for key preservation error or am I wrong? If this is the case, since i only need club_name from club table , can I use comma separated values to store multiple club names in a single cell so that the event table keys wont repeat for every club_name to resolve this issue?